# Unable to locate package gcc

Tags: apt, upgrade, updates, lubuntu, gcc

I tried to install gcc compiler because I want to learn programming I have an old computer 1gb ram so I installed an older version of Ubuntu (10.04) and its working faster than before but when I try to install gcc package by writing

```
sudo apt-get install gcc
```

but the following text appear :

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
E: Unable to locate package gcc
```

so I said maybe the problem is that my version of ubuntu is too old so I wrote in the terminal

```
sudo get-apt upgrade
```

but this also appear to me

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
```

and I tried also

```
sudo apt-get update
```

but many lines appear and the last one was

```
E: Some index files failed to download, they have been ignored, or old ones used   instead
```

and I noticed also that this version of Ubuntu don't have a graphical package manager so .

Comment: r u using server version or desktop version of 10.04

Comment: desktop version

Comment: do u mean reinstall because i cant get even upgrade with sudo apt-get upgrade

Comment: http://askubuntu.com/questions/91815/how-to-install-software-or-upgrade-from-old-unsupported-release, this will help you...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Desktop version of 10.04 end the life so you can't install gcc using `apt-get`...

You should upgrade to latest version of Ubuntu.

To upgrade latest you can do with `sed`, first open terminal(<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd>) and type the following,

```
sudo sed -i -e 's/archive.ubuntu.com\|security.ubuntu.com/old-releases.ubuntu.com/g' /etc/apt/sources.list
```

then update with

```
sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get dist-upgrade
```

Comment: Ok but how to upgraded i nedd to reinstall it or just with terminal

Comment: Upgrading from 10.04 to 14.04 will take several steps. First you need to upgrade to 12.04 LTS and from there to 14.04 LTS. It may be easier/faster if you install 14.04 from scratch, but that depends on how much customisation you have done so far. Or, you could just upgrade to 12.04 as that will be supported for a few more years.

Comment: @user297904 I have updated answer please try it...

Comment: Ok i read the update and it works thanks a lot :D

Comment: @Whaaaaaat thank u for suggestion, I will consider in future...

Answer (score 0):

I would definitely not recommend installing older Ubuntu versions, given that there will be no security updates for them, leaving your system vulnerable for all kinds of attacks. 
Instead, it would be better to go for a lighter desktop edition, for example LUbuntu (or are you already using that give nthat this post is tagged with lubuntu).

As to the missing gcc and the failing index files: maybe the Ubuntu mirror that you selected during installation no longer contains the files for older releases like Ubuntu 10.04. You can check the mirror that you are using in the file `/etc/apt/sources.list`. For example mine shows several references to the Dutch mirror: `http://nl.archive.ubuntu.com`.

Answer (score 0):

Which version of gcc do you want to install? All gcc release are in [here](ftp://ftp.mirrorservice.org/sites/sourceware.org/pub/gcc/releases/) just download what version of gcc if you want from  there and then install by your self. If you don't know how to install that, follow this question is answered [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/25961/how-do-i-install-a-tar-gz-or-tar-bz2-file).